# How can I get files and file names using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file, web

I am making a website that contains mainly static articles, and I wanted to just access .txt files from a directory and have the pages dynamically created that way when the site is loaded using JavaScript. However, I am struggling to find a way to get access to the files (The files would be in a folder wherever the site is being hosted along with the actual web pages and then I would be extracting the text from these files and creating the pages that way). Is this at all possible without having to use server side code or are there any recommendations for creating the pages another way? I would really like to avoid going through all of the trouble of continually adding html pages for every single article as that would be pretty monotonous and I currently don't have any back-end code and would like to keep it that way if possible. Any recommendations in general would be appreciated.

Comment: "_Is this at all possible without having to use server side code_" No, it isn't. Think about security, if any arbitrary client code could access the file system of your server.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without a backend server. Code running in browser is not allowed to access the files on the system due to security reasons.

Either write a simple backend service to fetch those text file or access those text file data by converting the text files as JavaScript files and declaring text data as variables. Then load these files before your main JavaScript file. Now you can access the data as variables in your main js script.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in the traditional open file, read file and close file paradigm.

You could create a web service on your server that would return data from a file using ajax, such as the contents of the text file. But without any backend code, it will not be possible since there would be a lot of security implications if the client-side code was able to do so without any server-side code.